# How can I display the result of my sqlite query in a html django page

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have the following query set in my `views.py`:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    #cursor.execute("SELECT  AgentName FROM 'CSQ Agent Report' ")
    cursor.execute("SELECT  'AgentName', count (*) FROM 'CSQ Agent Report' WHERE  'AgentName' != 'None'  AND 'OriginatorDNHANDELED' = '1' or 'OriginatorDNNOTHANDELED' = '1' Group by 'AgentName'")
    obj = cursor.fetchall()
context = {
    'object': obj
            }



return render(request,"CSQ/detail.html", context)
```

And I would like to display the result of the query in my html page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1> Stats Call Center Of Feb </h1>
<p> Nb of calls received by agent </p>
<ul>
{% for var in object %}
    <li> {{var}} </li>
{% endfor %}


</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

I have the same query created in python and it works as expected :

```
cursor.execute(""" SELECT  "AgentName", count (*) FROM "CSQ Agent Report" WHERE  "AgentName" != "None"  AND "OriginatorDNHANDELED" = '1' or "OriginatorDNNOTHANDELED" = '1' Group by "AgentName"  """)

liste8= cursor.fetchall()

for i in range (len(liste8)):
    
    print (liste8[i][0],liste8[i][1])
```

and the result in python is as follow :

```
Agent1 11
Agent2 41
Agent3 249
Agent4 46
Agent5 2
Agent6 216
Agent7 117
Agent8 242
Agent9 50
```

I would like to display the same resulat in my Html Django page as per python .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the query is returning nested arrays. You can use the following code in order to get a similar output as the python console. (The appearance might be different for which you will have to apply CSS but the pattern should be the same.)

```
`{% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% block content %}
 <h1> Stats Call Center Of Feb </h1>
 <p> Nb of calls received by agent </p>
 <ul>
 {% for var in object %}
    {% for i in var%}
          <li> {{i.AgentName}} &nbsp {{i.OriginatorDNHANDELED (use the names you use in the 
            Model)}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
   </ul>
 {% endblock %}`
```

Comment: I hav updated the html file as per your recommendations but i still got blank page . % extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1> Stats Call Center Of Feb </h1>
<p> Nb of calls received by agent </p>
<ul>
 {% for var in object %}
  {% for i in var%}
      <li> {{i.AgentName}} &nbsp {{i.OriginatorDNHANDELED}} </li>
  {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}

</ul>

{% endblock %}

Comment: Have you set up any model for this query, if so please share the code in the specific model class?

Comment: @walid can you please elaborate on why are you not using the Model instance for querying and querying the database manually. There is no point in doing that.

Comment: Hi , I alreay have a model but didn't find how to add the model in the posted question . Regarding your question , what do you mean by using Model instance for querying ? can you provide an example ? . I'm a novice in jango and i'm not familiar with Django Jargon . haks

Comment: Can you please show your model which is handling this?

Comment: It should be in the same directory as views.py file.

Comment: Hi , I have changed the way of querying the DB based on model instances instead of raw queries . Now i'm able to display dat from DB  Thanks for your support

Comment: Yeah! That's the way to do it. Otherwise, there is no point in using built-in Django queries which are awesome.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, mark your question resolved with the above answer so that others can also take advantage in case of stucking in similar problem.